# Django 1.7.1 Makemigrations fails when using lambda as default for attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models, lambda, django-migrations

I'm using Django 1.7.1. My model looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models

class myModel(models.Model):
    x = models.CharField(max_length=254,null=True, blank=True,)
```

Everything works perfectly fine.

However, when I add the following attribute to myModel, it breaks:

```
    y = models.DateTimeField(default=lambda: datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1), editable=False)
```

`manage.py makemigrations` gives me the following error:

> ValueError: Cannot serialize function: lambda

This seems like a known bug: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.django.scm/125724

So how can I work around it? I need the value of `y` to be automatically set by default to 24 hours from the moment the model was created.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The [migrations documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#serializing-values) addresses this:

> Migrations are just Python files containing the old definitions of your models - thus, to write them, Django must take the current state of your models and serialize them out into a file. While Django can serialize most things, there are some things that we just can’t serialize out into a valid Python representation....
>
> Django can serialize the following: Any function or method reference... in module’s top-level scope
>
> Django cannot serialize: Lambdas

So the solution is simple: instead of a lambda, define a regular function and refer to it by name.

```
def one_day_hence():
    return datetime.utcnow() + timezone.timedelta(days=1)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    y = models.DateTimeField(default=one_day_hence)
```

Comment: You should use django timezone.now instead of datetime.utcnow

Comment: @besil: No, because this answer is about how to properly structure the OP's code, and they chose to use `datetime.utcnow`.

Comment: ok, formally you are right. But generally is a best practice to use django timezone instead of datetime module, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error below:

> ValueError: Cannot serialize function <built-in method date of datetime.datetime object at 0x0000019D077B70F0>: No module

When I set [timezone.now().date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) to [DateField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield) as [a default value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default) as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class MyModel(models.Model):              # Error      
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now().date)
```

So, I set `current_date` without `()` which returns `timezone.now().date()` to `DateField()` as a default value as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

def current_date(): # Here
    return timezone.now().date()

class MyModel(models.Model):        # Here      
    date = models.DateField(default=current_date)
```

Be careful, I can set `timezone.now().date()` with `()` to `DateField()` as a default value without error as shown below, but the default date becomes when the Django server starts (Unchanged):

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class MyModel(models.Model):                    # Here ↓↓      
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now().date())
```

In addition, I don't recommend to use `DateField()` and [TimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#timefield) because they don't work with [TIME_ZONE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-TIME_ZONE) in `settings.py` as I asked [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383841/how-to-set-the-current-proper-date-and-time-to-datefield-and-timefield-r) while [DateTimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) does.

Comment: cool, save my ass. Thank you!