# Creating a default ID in Django from a function and prefix string

Tags: python, django, django-models

What I need to do is run a function and append a prefix to the beginning of the results returned from that function. This needs to be done each time a new instance is created of my model.

What I have tried....

The following won't work because you cannot add a string to a function and would set the ID as `s_<function name etc>` and not the results of the function.

```
APP_PREFIX = "_s"
id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, unique=True,
                      default="{}{}".format(APP_PREFIX, make_id))
```

Nor will passing the prefix to the function because Django will generate the same key each time calling the function this way, no idea why tho:

```
id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, unique=True,
                      default=make_id(APP_PREFIX))
```

This won't work either:

```
id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, unique=True,
                      default=make_id + APP_PREFIX)
```

Or this:

```
id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, unique=True,
                      default=make_id() + APP_PREFIX)
```

How can this be achieved?

I could overwrite the `save()` method and achieve this but there must be a way to do this with the default parameter on the field!

Comment: You're not actually calling the function in the first example, have you tried calling it?

Comment: @IanAuld yep and you get violates unique constraint on any object you create after the first., if I call it i.e. ``default=make_id()`` Django seem to call it just the once and not each time on creating a new instance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649659/how-to-set-a-django-model-fields-default-value-to-a-function-call-callable-e

Comment: @IanAuld read that, but does not apply as he is adding 2 dates together. What I need to do is run a function and append a prefix to the beginning of the results returned.

Comment: If the result of your function is a string, which it is, format should work fine. Alternatively if concatenating them inside the field definition won't work just change your function to `return 's_' + base64.b64encode(uuid.uuid4().bytes).decode("utf-8")`

Comment: @IanAuld ``s_`` is actually dynamic so thats not applicable.

Comment: How about using the `pre_save` signal https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save and setting the value there?

Comment: @AdrianGhiuta I could also do it in the ``save()`` method but  I would really like to find away to do this with the default parameter on the field if possible :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to achieve this on my model:

```
PREFIX = settings.PREFIXES['THIS']
def get_id():
  return make_id(PREFIX)

    class MyModel(models.Model):
        id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,unique=True,
                                  default=get_id,)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom manager for your model and override the `create()` method. Then, in the `create()` method you can generate the ID field by explicitly calling the `make_id` function. The only thing is that you should not set the default property for the id field.

So the model would look something like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, unique=True)
  objects = MyModelManager()
```

Then, the implementation of `MyModelManager` should look something like this:

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
  def create(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs['id'] = make_id()
    return super(MyModelManager, self).create(**kwargs)
```

Of course, you should add to the create method any other parameters you need for the creation of instances of your model.

Creating an object instance of `MyModel` is then done by:

```
my_model = MyModel.objects.create()
```

Alternatively, if you'd like to use the default property, the following should work for you:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  APP_PREFIX = "_s"
  id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, unique=True,
                        default=lambda: generate_id(MyModel.APP_PREFIX))

def generate_id(prefix):
  return make_id() + prefix
```

Comment: That solution would work, but I don't believe this cannot be done using the default parameter. I would like to hear if this is possible.

Comment: I understand. Just verified it and the solution in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649659/how-to-set-a-django-model-fields-default-value-to-a-function-call-callable-e) post should work for you. If you'd like I can edit the answer with a suggested solution based on it.

Comment: Edited the answer with the suggested default based solution.

Comment: I like the lambda soultion however when I try to use it I get ``/migrations/writer.py", line 388, in serialize
    raise ValueError("Cannot serialize function: lambda")``

Comment: It seems from read more lambda cannot be used because of migrations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072222/django-1-7-1-makemigrations-fails-when-using-lambda-as-default-for-attribute

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting the `save` method should be simple to implement:

```
from django.db import models

class YourModel(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, unique=True)
    # other fields for YourModel

    def make_id():
        return base64.b64encode(uuid.uuid4().bytes).decode("utf-8")

    def save(self, *args, ***kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.id = self.make_id()
        super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Eventually `make_id` is not a method of `YourModel`, but that is just a slight change in the code. In the method `save` you can concatenate "s_" or whatever you need. The id is generated only if the entry hasn't got any id (meaning it doesn't yet exist).

Using `self.pk` might be an alternative (and maybe) better approach. You could omit the explicit creation of the field `id`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already know I could do this but as I said in the OP there must be a way to do this with the default parameter on the field :)

Comment: I read your comment regarding ``save()`` after I wrote my answer. I'm sorry, but I also have no idea how to do it with the default parameter.

Comment: No problem, what you have would work, but I would like to first explore how this can be achieved on the field :)

Answer (score 1):

Tip: Use functools to create callable.
The example below will generate prefixed hash like `tag_HKh7788GjhbJu8K`

```
import random
import string
from functools import partial

class PrefixedHashField(models.CharField):

    @staticmethod
    def gen_value(prefix, hash_length):
        hashtext = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=hash_length))
        return f"{prefix}_{hashtext}"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        prefix = kwargs.pop('prefix')
        hash_length = kwargs.pop("hash_length")
        kwargs['default'] = partial(self.gen_value, prefix, hash_length)
        super(PrefixedHashField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class Tag(models.Model):
    id = PrefixedHashField(primary_key=True, prefix="tag", hash_length=15, max_length=30)
```